# How do I sort data from a CSV by a column?

Tags: python, csv

I need to organise a CSV file by user ID in ascending order. The csv file has a header that I would like to keep at the top of the document.
the headers are below with 13500 rows of data

```
User_ID;firstname;lastname;location
```

The code i have currently omits the headings. If I remove the `heading=next(csv_reader)` line, it puts the headings at the bottom of the document.

The current output does not also put them in correct order but goes off the first value of the ID and not the whole number (ID=13000 comes before ID=2000 through 9999)

```
import csv
import operator
file = open("file.csv", 'r')

csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')

heading=next(csv_reader)

sort = sorted(csv_reader, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline)
```

Comment: If you want to print the header before your data, do that! Remember that the header is not part of the `sort` list-of-lists, because you pulled it out in the `heading = ...` line

Comment: Your current sort happens in _lexical order_, because the elements of your CSV file are _strings_. If you want to sort them as integers, have your `key` function in the `sorted` call convert them to integers.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the part that was irrelevant to the question about sorting your data. If you have a question about randomly changing last names, and adding titles, please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Your current sort happens in [*lexical order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), because the elements of your CSV file are *strings*. If you want to sort them as integers, have your `key` function in the `sorted` call convert them to integers.

```
sorted_data = sorted(csv_reader, key=lambda row: int(row[0]))
```

I used a lambda instead of `operator.itemgetter(0)` because we needed to convert to an `int` anyway, and this is the most convenient way to do so.

To print the header with the data, print it before printing your data:

```
print(heading)
for line in sorted_data
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with `pandas` too:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(open('file.csv'), delimiter=';')
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=["User_ID"], ascending=True)
sorted_df.to_csv('file_sorted.csv', sep=';', index=False)

print(sorted_df.to_string(index=False))
```